# UNIX Shell programming - inventory program

Tags: shell, unix, inventory

The code below contains my add function of my code , according to the requirement it need to satisfy on simple thing , which i am unable to accomplish
-> when the book name and the author name is being inputted it works fine , but in case of

->Existing title and different author (it doesn't works) it needs to give the output as " book name added successfully " 
instead of showing , book already exists  ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv071.png)

*I have a txt file which stores the list of details of set of books (bookdb.txt)

Can Some one help me to sort this out.

```
function add_new_book
{
echo "1) add_new_book"
    echo -n "Title :"
        read title
    echo -n "Author :"
        read author
    echo -n "Price :"
        read price
    echo -n "Qty Available  : "
        read available 
    echo -n "Qty Sold : "
        read sold 
            grep "$title" BookDB.txt >/dev/null 2>&1
                rc=$?
if [[ "$rc" != 0 ]]; then
        echo $title:$author:$price:$available:$sold >> BookDB.txt

    echo $BookDB "New book title ' $title ' added successfully "
    else
        echo "The book $title already exists."
fi

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if i understand your question correct. If you wish to supress duplicates in case of Title AND Autor is the same, but allow combinations of same Title different Author or the other way round, i suggest to change the grep command to:

```
grep ".*$title.*$author" BookDB.txt >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Only if both, title AND author are found in one of your DB lines, the book gets rejected.

```
someone@somwhere ~/test $ ./test.sh 
1) add_new_book
Title :test
Author :aaa
Price :12
Qty Available  : 12
Qty Sold : 12
New book title ' test ' added successfully 
someone@somwhere ~/test $ ./test.sh 
1) add_new_book
Title :test
Author :aaa 
Price :12
Qty Available  : 12
Qty Sold : 12
The book test already exists.
someone@somwhere ~/test $ ./test.sh 
1) add_new_book
Title :test
Author :abc
Price :12
Qty Available  : 12
Qty Sold : 12
New book title ' test ' added successfully
```

Comment: All correct, but attention with `".*$title.*$author"`. This pattern may match unwanted keys.

Answer (score 0):

So you should `grep` for "unique key" $title:$author:

```
grep "^$title:$author:" BookDB.txt >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ "$?" != "0" ]
then
   echo $title:$author:$price:$available:$sold >> BookDB.txt
   echo $BookDB "New book title ' $title ' added successfully "
else
   echo "The book $title already exists."
fi
```